# excluding things in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query to exclude certain paramters from a table. here is my query:

```
SELECT  RULE_NAME AS "Rule Name", COUNT( RULE_NAME ) AS "Event_cnt" 
FROM EVENTS_VW
WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE RULE_NAME LIKE
('Reporting_%')
 AND EVENT_DT >=  '2016-12-01 00:00:00.0' AND EVENT_DT <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00.0'
GROUP BY RULE_NAME ORDER BY EVENT_CNT DESC
```

Rules i would like to exclude in the above query are:

```
Reporting_deleted_mail
Reporting_fwd_mail
```

How do I modify the above query to accommodate the two rules I'm trying to exclude please?

Comment: `AND RULE_NAME NOT LIKE 'Reporting_deleted_mail'`   and `AND RULE_NAME NOT LIKE 'Reporting_fwd_mail'`

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your WHERE clause (before the GROUP BY clause):

```
AND RULE_NAME NOT IN ('Reporting_deleted_mail', 'Reporting_fwd_mail')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE RULE_NAME LIKE ('Reporting_%') 
AND RULE_NAME NOT IN ('Reporting_deleted_mail', 'Reporting_fwd_mail')
```

Answer (score 0):

i appreciate your quick feedback. The final solution is:

```
SELECT  
   RULE_NAME AS "Rule Name", 
   COUNT( RULE_NAME ) AS "Event_cnt" 
FROM 
   EVENTS_VW WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
   RULE_NAME LIKE ('Reporting_%') 
   AND RULE_NAME NOT IN ('Reporting_deleted_mail', 'Reporting_fwd_mail')
    AND EVENT_DT >=  '2016-12-01 00:00:00.0' AND EVENT_DT <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00.0'
GROUP BY 
   RULE_NAME 
ORDER BY 
   EVENT_CNT DESC
```

thank you kindly!
Sam